# Is there Smart Contract for IOTA distributed ledger technology

Tags: contract-development

IOTA is a distributed ledger technology based on directed acyclic graph data structure such that there is neither block nor chain.

The question is that is it possible to develop a Smart Contract for this new technology similar to ethereum ? And if so, it's exactly similar to ethereum smart contract?

IOTA web site: https://www.iota.org

Comment: by definition IOTA does not use a blockchain it uses a tangle, so i'm not sure what you mean by your question. building a tangle on a blockchain ?

Comment: @Mheni I mean deveping a smart contract for IOTA like developing smart contract for ethereum.

Comment: You'll want to ask this on the IOTA SE board: iota.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Richard Horrocks could you transfer it to iota.stackexchange.com ? or must be done by me ? Thanks.

Comment: I've flagged it as off-topic - one of the moderators should get to it - they have the power to migrate it :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to this article :

- [About Smart Contracts in IOTA](https://medium.com/@ralf/about-smart-contracts-in-iota-626d2bd3619e)

which is published by one of the board members of IOTA

IOTA does not support smart contracts natively, and it will be added as a layer on top of the tangle, and it is not available for the moment and they are still working on it.

> Let’s be very clear: As of this writing, IOTA does not “natively”
>   support smart contracts. The IOTA Foundation has publicly stated, that
>   smart contracts will not be a feature of the IOTA core but provided as
>   a layer on top. And it’s also public knowledge, that IOTA Foundation
>   is actively working on this additional smart contracts layer which
>   will likely need until the end of 2018 to become GA.